# Icon in Src folder

Tags: java, icons, jlabel, src

I am trying to create an icon for a jLabel using an image in my src folder. 
I am not sure of the file path I would use when creating this icon.

```
if (CoverImg.equals("")) {
   Icon noImage = new ImageIcon("/animedb/NoImage.jpg");
   CoverImageLabel.setIcon(noImage);
   CoverImageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
   } 
else {
   Icon icon = new ImageIcon(CoverImg);
   height = icon.getIconHeight();
   width = icon.getIconWidth();

   CoverImageLabel.setIcon(icon);
   CoverImageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
   }
```

CoverImageLabel is the jLabel

CoverImg is a String that contains a file path obtained from a database. If there is no file path available I want it to display the `NoImage.jpg` which is in my src folder. I am using Netbeans IDE, if that is at all relevant.

Can anyone help?

Comment: [How to Use Icons: Loading Images Using `getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource)

Answer (score 0):

```
CoverImageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(TYPE_YOUR_CLASS_NAME_HERE.class.getResource("/animedb/NoImage.jpg")));
```

As you can see I merged them all into one line, but you can create variables and separate them into multiple lines.  Good luck, let me know if there are any issues.